# Issues with directories and paths in a PHP project

Tags: php, html, url, href, absolute-path

I am having trouble figuring out this path problem. As you can see the highlighted  tag is located in a file called admin_navigation.php and the href is going one directory up from includes folder which is admin and to the file posts.php. The absolute path seems correct to me and the to Phpstorm but the PHP server jumps to this location "http://localhost/cms/posts.php?source=add_post" but instead, it is supposed to go to "http://localhost/cms/admin/posts.php?source=add_post". I'd appreciate it if someone can explain this weird behavior to me.

[image]

Comment: try with ./posts.php?source=add_post

Comment: So strange.. which server are you using?

Comment: @Jacks that one works but still doesn't make sense at all since that points to the includes folder.  for the server, I tried both Apache and PHP-server that comes with Phpstorm.  The same issue on both. My concern is why that happens.

Comment: Your `admin_navigation.php` is in a folder called `/includes`. I take it this file is included on another page as an `include()`. In that case the `../` would be relative to *that* folder. What page are you seeing the link on?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes I am using include with admin_navigation.php on other pages, The link is on admin_navigation.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link files with [`include()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), you're not 'referencing' them per se, but *copying* the contents of the target file to the file with `include()`.

Let's say you're including `admin_navigation.php` on `/admin/index.php` with `include('includes/admin_navigation.php')` or similar. This essentially *copies* the contents of `admin_navigation.php` into `index.php`. Now `index.php` contains the exact same link - `<a href="../posts.php?source=add_post">add posts</a>`.

As such, `index.php` looks one level up from `/admin`, and attempts to find `posts.php` in `CMS` -- which it can't, as the file doesn't exist there.

Note that this process applies to **every** file that you include `admin_navigation.php` in, so if you have multiple references from multiple different folders, then you'll have to have an absolute path in order for *all* files to reference the target correctly.

This would be done with `<a href="/CMS/admin/posts.php?source=add_post">add posts</a>`.

Alternatively, if you're only including `admin_navigation.php` on files in the `admin` folder ( `categories`, `index` and `posts`), you can simply omit the parent folder navigation in the relative path: `<a href="posts.php?source=add_post">add posts</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

As per you folder structure you should have used

**./posts.php?source=add_post**

this means that you have your **posts.php** file present in one level up of **admin_navigation.php** (ie. 
http://localhost/cms/admin/posts.php?source=add_post)

If you are giving
**../posts.php?source=add_post**

it will search for a file presents 2 levels up of **admin_navigation.php** (ie. http://localhost/cms/posts.php?source=add_post)